# Как выровнять текст с права от изображения

Tags: html, изображения, text, img

```
<figure id="home"><img src="img/2.png"></figure>
   <figcaption>
          <p class="text">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nam eu nulla. Donec lobortis purus vel urna. Nunc laoreet lacinia nunc
          </p>
   </figcaption>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
.left {
  float: left;
}

.my-img {
  padding-right: 10px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<figure id="home"><img class="left my-img" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/473506797462896640/_M0JJ0v8.png"></figure>
<figcaption>
  <p class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nam eu nulla. Donec lobortis purus vel urna. Nunc laoreet lacinia nunc
  </p>
</figcaption>
```

Comment: Спасибо, уже сделал )

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте свойство `float:left` для картинки:

```
figure img {
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Не помогает, Уже пробовал

Comment: как это не помогает [ссылка](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VabPGR) Либо не понятно что ты хочешь сделать, пиши проблему подробнее

Answer (score 0):

Может быть сам параграф тоже float'ится, может быть эти 2 элемента не помещаются в контейнер. Приведи пример кода на том же jsFiddle - будет проще помочь.

Comment: Туда скинул результат не виден. Ресурс не знаком лучше здесь помогите )

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="so" style="display: inline-flex;">
<figure id="home"> <img src="img/2.png"></figure>
   <figcaption>
          <p class="text">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nam eu nulla. Donec lobortis purus vel urna. Nunc laoreet lacinia nunc
          </p>
   </figcaption>
</div>
```

Оберните это все в div, из style перенесите в свой css. Лучше конечно сделать разметку bootstrap.

Comment: Спасибо большое, сам уже разобрался ))